# XDebug on port 9000 with a virtual machine - EADDRINUSE :::9000

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, virtualbox, xdebug

I am running my Symfony application on a VirtualBox VM. PHP is running with XDebug, and it is properly configured. I know this because other people have managed to make it work with a snapshot of the same VM.

When I try to configure in VS Code XDebug, I use the following `launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I click on "Start Debugging: Listen for XDebug", I get the following error:

> ERROR: listen EADDRINUSE :::9000

I tried killing the process that is using that port... and for my surprise that was the virtual machine I was trying to connect to.

What did I miss in this configuration?

Comment: Switch to 9001 port or some another free port (in both php.ini and your editor). Other than that -- that port is already used by another app (VirtualBox as you have said) .. so you must configure that first ...as VSC is unable to start listening on that port,

Comment: Indeed that is a solution, but I rather not change the VM, as it comes from a snapshot we all share. Id like to find out why the others do not have this problem and I do.

Comment: Well -- you need to investigate at what point 9000 port becomes occupied by VirtualBox: use `netstat` or alike and see at what point it will become occupied; step by step. Maybe it's specific VM instance, or maybe it's some Docker- or php-fpm related; or it could be your custom settings etc. Plus, I have no clue what VM you are using there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself just about.

The problem was laying on the configuration of Virtualbox.

On the Network settings, there was a port forwarding for the port 9000, which blocked my debugger from running locally. Once removed, it worked without problem.

Comment: Thank you, man, so much, I dare to say you residually saved me, this question doesn't seem to be discussed much on the internet. I had a similar problem with docker, though here seem to be missing also a docker configuration of global host xdebug ip, or configured connect back option which both might prevent the functionality. – FantomX1 17 mins ago    Delete

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to do a `launch` operation in your `launch.json`, which will result as vscode trying to **start** a new instance of php **with an xdebug on port 9000**.

Try replacing your `launch` config by an `attach` config.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

port 9000 is frequently used by default configurations of other apps (for example native apache on MacOsX), also VMs, Docker containers, etc...

A reliable solution would be - to use a different port. For example, 9001 :)

That means:

- updating your IDE xdebug configs from port 9000 to 9001;
- adding to
  your php.ini (xdebug.ini) the line

  ```
  xdebug.remote_port=9001
  ```

Also, you can check your 9000 port usage by some tool like telnet

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS we can use the terminal to determine what is open on port 9000 with the following:

```
sudo lsof -nP -i4TCP:9000 | grep LISTEN
```

We can use sudo above so we see processes that are not owned by the logged in account.

For example when I did the above I got:

```
php-fpm 110 root    6u  IPv4 0x5cb825c4aa80be09      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm 261 _www    0u  IPv4 0x5cb825c4aa80be09      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm 262 _www    0u  IPv4 0x5cb825c4aa80be09      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
```

We can then end the processes with this command:

```
sudo kill 110
```

Then we will have the port free so we can start up Xdebug without a conflict.

That solved it for me.

Comment: This lsof command was helpful to point out the php-fpm started by a brew service. I couldn't kill -9 them and with sudo they would re-spawn. Not sure where they came from, maybe installing  valet. which i uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, sonarqube server was running on 9000 so I set xdebug to 9002.